# How to create a Cube using a default Named Set on Mondrian

Tags: olap, mondrian

I´ve created a Named Set on Mondrian and i need to define it as default for some cubes.
I did it with MDX using WHERE clause, but unfortunately the cube looses the where clause when the users work with Measures/Dimensions on OLAP Navigator.

```
    select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity1]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {[Dimension1].[All]} ON ROWS
    from [Cube]
    where [NamedSet1]
```

How to create a Cube using a default Named Set on Mondrian?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the approach and created a calculated member using the dimension as filter

The expression for calculated member `CMQuantity1` is like:

```
([Measures].[Quantity1], [Dimension1].[NamedSet1 scope])
```